# I keep on getting 'PeerIdInvalidError' when using Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am making a program that adds users to a group using phone number:

```
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone=phone, first_name=phone, last_name='add')
result = session(ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
user_input = InputPeerUser(result.users[0].id, result.users[0].access_hash)
session(functions.messages.AddChatUserRequest(user_id=user_input, fwd_limit=0, chat_id=import_chat.chats[0].id))
```

I keep on getting `PeerIdInvalidError` when running `AddChatUserRequest`

Edit: This algorithm works but it shows this error when adding some accounts. The error is caused by `AddChatUserRequest`

Comment: Are the phone numbers hidden for the users?

Comment: No they are not

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that the user has disabled or rejecting the feature to be added to groups by other users. If you have multiple accounts or know some of them, you could test this case.